# Twitter Bootstrap Datetimepicker go to date using a normal button

Tags: php, jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm working on a planner using bootstrap, php and jquery and i'd like to use a datetimepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to go to a different date on the planner and view the tasks of that day.
I want to use a normal button to trigger the datepicker. Then, whenever the user picked a date, use GET to create a link like index.php?page=planner&date=2013-08-03. I'm trying not to use an input field, but whenever a date is clicked to create a GET link immediately if possible..

**Example image:**

How to create a button working like this?
[image: example]

**I'm using the following HTML:**

```
<a id="diff-date" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Date <i class="icon-calendar icon-white"></i></a>
```

**An the following JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#diff-date').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
  });
```

Without succes so far.. I hope someone can help!

**EDIT**

**Normally I use this HTML:**

```
<label>Datum:</label>
<div id="datum" class="input-append">
     <input data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" type="text" name="datum" placeholder="Kies een     datum..." /><span class="add-on"><i data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

**And this JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#datum').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false
    });
});
```

**To achieve this:**

[image: example 2]

Comment: Somethink like `$('#diff_date').click(function() {$('#diff-date').datepicker('show')});`      
Are you sure you're using **"datetimepicker"** and not **"datepicker"**?

Comment: Hmm still not working. I'm sure about that. I'm using this one http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker. Whenever I use a input field it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing:

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

With this:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

They're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#diff_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
      var choosenDate = ev.date;
      //Add a specific treatment for the date here...
      $('#diff-date').datepicker('hide');
    });
    $('#diff_date').click(function() {
        $('#diff-date').datepicker('show');
    });
}
```

And change the html of your link like :

```
<a id="diff-date" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-20">Date <i class="icon-calendar icon-white"></i></a>
```

Just for information, this is the code used in the [site](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to make a link with a calendar :

```
var startDate = new Date(2012,1,20);
var endDate = new Date(2012,1,25);
$('#dp4').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()){
                    $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date can not be greater then the end date');
        } else {
            $('#alert').hide();
            startDate = new Date(ev.date);
            $('#startDate').text($('#dp4').data('date'));
        }
        $('#dp4').datepicker('hide');
    });
```

And the Html for that

```
Start date<a href="#" class="btn small" id="dp4" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-20">Change</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing happens

Comment: No still not working.. I've edited my question so you can see what I do when i'm using a input field. Which works fine.

Comment: I follow your link to http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ , and i don't understand why it dosen't work. Do you test only with my given code? Without your option `pickTime:false` and with `datepicker` instead of `datetimepicker`... You don't have time utility!

Comment: Ah I see what the confusion is.. I've used this one: http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ which is actually based on http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker. I'm sorry.. Are there also solutions for that 'tarruda' version?

Comment: Try to had an hidden input, and to add `datetimepicker` on it.  But for now, I think that youre plugin can't be plugged on another element than input! Or switch between datepicker for some links, and datetimepicker for others!